# Deserialize JSON data in MVVM Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, json, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I want to Deserialize data with Json.net in my Windows Phone 8 app but i run out of ideas. i have done this before and it worked but now that the data (json) has changed so the code must change too.

i use this to download my data:

```
var grad = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["grad"] as string;

            UriBuilder fullUri = new UriBuilder("http://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?");

            fullUri.Query = "q=" + grad + "&units=metric";

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadStringAsync(fullUri.Uri);
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += client_DownloadStringCompletedtrenutno;
```

this is set up in an methos in my MainViewModel.cs. Then i have an Event Handler after the Download

```
void client_DownloadStringCompletedtrenutno(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            RootObject4 json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject4>(e.Result);
            Trenutno = new ObservableCollection<Main4>(json.main4);
            Sada = Trenutno[0];

        }
        else
        {
            //display an error
        }
    }
```

I used jsontoc# to convert the jso ndata to these in my Model:

```
public class Coord4
{
    public double lon { get; set; }
    public double lat { get; set; }
}

public class Sys4
{
    public double message { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int sunrise { get; set; }
    public int sunset { get; set; }
}

public class Weather4
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }


}

public class Main4
{
    public int temp { get; set; }
    public int pressure { get; set; }
    public int humidity { get; set; }
    public int temp_min { get; set; }
    public int temp_max { get; set; }
}

public class Wind4
{
    public double speed { get; set; }
    public int deg { get; set; }
    public int var_beg { get; set; }
    public int var_end { get; set; }
}

public class Rain4
{
    public int __invalid_name__3h { get; set; }
}

public class Snow4
{
    public double __invalid_name__3h { get; set; }
}

public class Clouds4
{
    public int all { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject4
{
    public Coord4 coord4 { get; set; }
    public Sys4 sys4 { get; set; }
    public List<Weather4> weather4 { get; set; }
    public string @base { get; set; }
    public Main4 main4 { get; set; }
    public Wind4 wind4 { get; set; }
    public Rain4 rain4 { get; set; }
    public Snow4 snow4 { get; set; }
    public Clouds4 clouds4 { get; set; }
    public int dt4 { get; set; }
    public int id4 { get; set; }
    public string name4 { get; set; }
    public int cod4 { get; set; }
}
```

the problem is now in the DownloadCompleted Event handler it says me that the "Trenutno = new ObservableCollection(json.main4);" has some invalid arguments. but how?

if it helps here is the json data:

`{"coord":{"lon":18.65,"lat":44.45},"sys":{"message":0.0043,"country":"BA","sunrise":1385358909,"sunset":1385392200},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"base":"cmc stations","main":{"temp":2,"pressure":1014,"humidity":64,"temp_min":2,"temp_max":2},"wind":{"speed":5.1,"deg":300,"var_beg":280,"var_end":340},"rain":{"3h":0},"snow":{"3h":1.1},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1385380800,"id":3186423,"name":"Zivinice","cod":200}`

And this is the property i use to collect this data in MainViewModel.cs

```
public ObservableCollection<Main4> Trenutno
    {
        get
        {
            return _trenutno;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_trenutno == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging(TrenutnoPropertyName);
            _trenutno = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(TrenutnoPropertyName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ObservableCollection` [expects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `IEnumerable` as an input. However `json.main4` is a field of `Main4` type.

---

inside the client_DownloadStringCompletedtrenutno method:

```
Trenutno = json.main4;
```

and update the property in code:

```
private Main4 _trenutno;
public Main4 Trenutno
{
    get
    {
        return _trenutno;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_trenutno == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        RaisePropertyChanging(TrenutnoPropertyName);
        _trenutno = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(TrenutnoPropertyName);
    }
}
```

Comment: i added now some code how i use observable collection to get the data, how to modify it to make it works now?

Comment: updated. But I suggest you to spend some time to understand: why don't you need an ObservableCollection here?

Comment: no i dont need an Observable colletion, but how else do it? :) What should i use instead? i am open for everything that is better

Comment: better is just to use the class itself.

Comment: now it works :) thank you so much. and i have just a little question, what if i want to collect the data from Sys4, Weather4 and so on, should i use the same method?! make an property like you showed me and then the same way?

Comment: Thank you i made it, just another little question, what about the classes that are not represented as their own. like "name" it is only in the RootObject. how to display them?

Comment: make another property and assign json.name4 to it.

Comment: thnx so much, i will try. :)